# Declare and set Click Event for Button in different Layout - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to navigate to a different Layout(`Settings.axml`) from `Main.axml` via `ImageButton` Click. The `ImageButton` click to change Layout to `Settings.axml` is working fine, however I cannot figure out how to go back to `Main.axml` as I cannot declare the `ImageButton` in `MainActivity.cs` in the `OnCreate` Method.

Is there a way to Declare and use a Click Event for that Layout?

MainActivity.cs Code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                ActionBar.Hide();

                //Declare Buttons
                ImageButton btnSettings = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettings);
                ImageButton btnSettingsBack = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnSettingsBack);
                btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);

                lvNotes = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);

               dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

                //Load Data
                LoadNoteList();

                //Declare Button Click
                btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
                btnSettings.Click += BtnSettings_Click;
                btnSettingsBack.Click += BtnSettingsBack_Click;

            }
private void BtnSettingsBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        private void BtnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Settings);
        }
```

Comment: What is Settings.axml? Is a standard activity, how are you launching//invoking it? A `PreferenceScreen`-based layout, etc... Add your `BtnSettings_Click` code to your question...

Comment: `Settings.axml` is the Settings page for my app, See updated `MainActivity.cs` Code in question.

Comment: You will want to start another activity for your `Settings.axml` and not switch the content view for the activity you are already within....

Comment: How would i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Xamarin has a guide for this: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/

Comment: Yes but what would be inside the activity?

Comment: Will be will loading your `Settings.axml` as the content view for that new activity, you can than assign variables to hold UI elements (FindViewById) and handle any button clicks, etc... Think of each `Activity` as an *independent* app, they have their own set of variables, ui elements, lifecycle, etc...

Comment: So would I declare the `Settings.axml` UI Button and Click inside `MainActivity.cs` or the new Activity?

Comment: The setting.axml and all its ui element references, etc... would go in the ***new*** activity